# How to retrieve data from ms sql to text view in android studio

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server

I am trying to get data from a table in ms sql server into a textview in android

i have tried every thing including Async tasks and doinbackground but no have worked

here is my code:

```
 private TextView fam;
    private TextView inf;
    private boolean success = false; // boolean
    private ConnectionClass connectionClass; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inside__families);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        fam = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ttl2);
        fam.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Family"));
        inf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);


        connectionClass = new ConnectionClass(); 



        SyncData orderData = new SyncData();
        orderData.execute("");
    }


    private class SyncData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String msg = "No Data Found";
        ProgressDialog progress;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(Inside_Families.this, "Synchronising",
                    "Please Wait...", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings)  
        {
            try {
                Connection conn = connectionClass.CONN(); 
                if (conn == null) {
                    msg = "Please Check Your Connection";
                    success = false;
                } else if (fam.getText().equals("القحطاني")) {


                    String query = "SELECT Info FROM faminfo";
                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);


                    if (rs != null) 
                    {
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            try {
                                inf.setText((rs.getString("Info")));
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        msg = "Found";
                        success = true;
                    } else {
                        msg = "No Data found!";
                        success = false;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
                msg = writer.toString();
                success = false;
            }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String
                                             msg) 
        {
            progress.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(Inside_Families.this, msg + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (success == false) {
            } else {
                try {

                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

the problem that it doesn't retrieve data into the text view and that is what the logcat shows:

```
2019-08-04 19:16:26.465 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
2019-08-04 19:16:26.465 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:8530)
2019-08-04 19:16:26.465 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1432)
2019-08-04 19:16:26.465 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:23224)
2019-08-04 19:16:26.466 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail I/chatty: uid=10275(u0_a275) AsyncTask #2 identical 4 lines
2019-08-04 19:16:26.466 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:23224)
2019-08-04 19:16:26.466 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:360)
2019-08-04 19:16:26.466 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:23224)
2019-08-04 19:16:26.466 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:9789)
2019-08-04 19:16:26.466 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6023)
2019-08-04 19:16:26.466 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5849)
2019-08-04 19:16:26.466 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5806)
2019-08-04 19:16:26.466 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err:     at com.gohool.firstlook.algbail.Inside_Families$SyncData.doInBackground(Inside_Families.java:79)
2019-08-04 19:16:26.466 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err:     at com.gohool.firstlook.algbail.Inside_Families$SyncData.doInBackground(Inside_Families.java:48)
2019-08-04 19:16:26.466 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
2019-08-04 19:16:26.467 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2019-08-04 19:16:26.467 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
2019-08-04 19:16:26.467 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
2019-08-04 19:16:26.467 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
2019-08-04 19:16:26.467 32026-32495/com.gohool.firstlook.algbail W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Can someone please help me with that task?!

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You need a server side API to connect to the server to retrieve data and from your app, you need to communicate with that API to get data from the server and show them in your app. There are many ways depending on the situation like volley/glide. See for some tutorials relating them

Answer (score 0):

Your error says: *Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.*

It is because of this line

`inf.setText((rs.getString("Info")));`

While using **AsyncTask** please keep in mind that **DO NOT UPDATE THE VIEWS FROM BACKGROUND THREAD.** You are getting error cause you are trying to set text from the background thread.

To solve your error, move all the task which updates UI(like setText) to **onPostExecute()** method, which is generally the best practice.

Or if you want to make some UI changes from **doInBackground** thread, you can try something like this,

```
doInBackground() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // some code #3 (Write your code here to run in UI thread)
                    inf.setText((rs.getString("Info")));
                }
            });
}
```